# data persistence when user quits the app

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm dealing with an application that contains two table view controllers and one "detail" view to edit what's in the cell of the second table view. segues is used to navigate between the two table view controllers. when an object  is edited in the second table and go back to the previous table, the editing is saved there but when i'm in the second table and restart the app, the app doesn't save although when an edit occurs the context does go  through the save: function. Note: the entities in the first table view has a one-to-many relationship with the entities of the second table.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried setting up a protocol in the second table view and pass the update to the first table view, but this needs the user to go back to the first table if the protocol needs to work. and i tried this which i actually finding more hope in it: when the user navigates to the second view, through the prepareForSegue i pass an NSManagedObject to it (which saves it as an @property there) then i do the change on it when an updated immediately happens in the second table. however it didn't work. the updated didn't save as well although the context undergoes save:

Comment: Include the code that represents your attempt, with a detailed description for where its failing.

Comment: i deleted everything cause i felt like i'm doing something wrong :S however i do have a question that might solve my problem. when using custom delegation, can i create a delegation in the first table (.h) file and use it in the second table after that? i usually create custom delegation from the cild view to the parent view? and in custom delegation when a view needs to appear (case of going from child to parent view) does the protocol method is called before ViewWillApppear or ViewWillAppear first and then the protocol ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user should expect edits to be saved as they are made (as opposed to only after clicking a "Save" button), then you have a couple of options:

You could simply set up your tableViewController as the delegate of your detailViewController, and save edits as they are made using events that occur on the detailViewController view (i.e. UITextFieldDelegate, etc.).

It might be better, though, to keep the same delegate pattern in the previous setup, but only call the save function when the user either exits the detailViewController view or when they close the app.

Something like the following could work.

**TableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <DetailViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

.

**TableViewController.m**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)editObject:(MyManagedObject *)object {
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [DetailViewController new];
    detailVC.myObject = object;
    detailVC.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}

- (void)detailViewControllerDidFinishWithObject:(id)object {
    // Your saving functions
}

@end
```

.

**DetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate;

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DetailViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyManagedObject *myObject;

@end



@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)detailViewControllerDidFinishWithObject:(MyManagedObject *)object;

@end
```

.

**DetailViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize myObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do your normal view loading things

    // Register a notification to know the app will terminate
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:)
                                                 name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [delegate detailViewControllerDidFinishWithObject:myObject];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [delegate detailViewControllerDidFinishWithObject:myObject];
}

@end
```